# What is the purpose of moving a register to itself as in "mov (%eax), eax"?

Tags: assembly, x86

While disassembling simple C code with GCC I came across:

```
mov (%eax), eax
```

My understanding of assembly is that when you have `()` surrounding a register, you are adding some number to the memory address, i.e., `0x4(%eax)` would mean 4 bytes above the register `%eax`.

Here, however, there is no number before the `()`, so it appears to be copying the value in the register to itself.

I have noticed that the `%eax` register is used quite commonly to return variables and this line occurs immediately after a function call, so my guess is that this instruction is actually telling the machine to take whatever was in the `%eax` register for the called function (i.e., the return value) and put in the `%eax` register for the current function.

Is this correct? If not, what have I got wrong, and what is it actually doing?

Comment: I would recommend using Intel syntax over AT&T syntax. It is much easier to read IMO.

Comment: That should be `mov (%eax),%eax`. This just copies the longword at address `EAX` into the `EAX` register.

Comment: @Jonathon: That really depends what you were raised on.

Comment: @TonyK Hence the "In my opinion"....

Comment: @Jonathon: Presumably, in your opinion, Intel syntax is objectively better. Otherwise you wouldn't have recommended it. I was just pointing out that this is a highly subjective question.

Comment: IOW, in Intel syntax, it is `mov eax,[eax]`, which gets the 32 bit value stored at the address in eax and stores the result in eax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`()` in at&t syntax denotes memory dereferencing, you should probably read about the effective address syntax. The equivalent C code would be `eax=*eax;` meaning, load the 4 bytes from memory using the current value of `eax` as address, and overwrite `eax` with the fetched value.

Function calls and returns do not affect the values of registers (except stack and instruction pointer of course), there is no notion of `eax` of the caller or the callee.

PS: you can switch `gdb` into intel syntax mode using `set disassembly-flavor intel`, if you are not happy with at&t.